# Multiple columns hierarchical view

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I’m trying to display my subcategories in a hierarchical view but can’t seem to figure it out with a formula rather than with pivot tables or scripts

What I have:

```
A     |B            |C
Equity|International|aaa
Equity|U.S.         |bbb
Bond  |U.S.         |ccc
Equity|Canadian     |ddd
```

What I’m trying to achieve:

```
A
Equity
   Canadian
      ddd
   U.S 
      bbb
   International
      aaa
Bond
   U.S.
      ccc
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What are you expecting as solution? Are looking for a formula, a script, an add-on, or other something completely different? If you are looking for a formula or a script please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts. If you are looking for a software recommendation the question is off-topic here, try [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: Thanks! I’m looking for a formula to achieve the desired results

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: This can be done via formula, but I will tell you that it will be quite a task. You can increase your chances of someone taking this on if you will share a link to a spreadsheet, even if all you have in that spreadsheet is exactly what you show in your post. It will give people a starting point, a place to test and a place to leave solutions they might be able to devise. Just be sure, when creating such a link, that you set the Share permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: Also, make SURE that your sample data accurately reflects the nature of your actual data. For instance, your sample data shows three columns/levels. If someone chooses to work on this using that information, and then you reveal that you actually have four or five sublevels, you will have wasted a lot of someone's time. So again, be sure you are accurately conveying the nature of your data up front.